# How add Component with in react.js with reactHook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components

I make some lists that show area, subarea.
Link to UI

[image]

The top of the screen shows the city. If someone clicked that button, a subarea in the city that was clicked appears at the bottom of the Screen.

City list comes from open API, so I coded like under.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';
import SubArea from './SubArea';

const Restaurant = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState();
const serviceKey = "myserviceKey"; // 서비스키 입력
let areaList = [];

const api = (code) => {
    const areaCode = code;
    const url = `http://api.visitkorea.or.kr/openapi/service/rest/KorService/areaCode?ServiceKey=${serviceKey}&areaCode=${areaCode}&numOfRows=10&pageNo=1&MobileOS=ETC&MobileApp=AppTest`;

    axios
        .get(url)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
            const areaCode = res.data.response.body.items.item;

            setData(areaCode);
            subArea(areaCode);
        })
}

const subArea = (areaCode) => {
    let i = 1;
    let length = 0;

    while (areaCode[i] != null) { //obj 크기 계산하는 반복문
        length++;
        i++;
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        areaList.push(areaCode[index].name);
    }

    return areaList;
}

return (
    <div>
        <Link to="./"><img className="backicon" src={backicon} alt="backicon"/></Link>
        <h1 className="header2">위치설정</h1>
        <p className="normalfont">찾고 싶은 위치 및 장소를 입력하세요</p>
        <div className="btn_class">
            <form action="search.php" method="post">
                <input className="btn_text" type="text"/>
                <input className="btn_submit" type="submit" value="SEARCH"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <p className="findingplace">광역시</p>
        <div className="containerList">
            <button
                className="itemList"
                onClick={() => {
                    api(1)
                }}>서울시</button>
            <button
                className="itemList"
                onClick={() => {
                    api(2)
                }}>인천시</button>
            <button
                className="itemList"
                onClick={() => {
                    api(3)
                }}>대전시</button>
            {/* <button
                className="itemList"
                onClick={() => {
                    api(4)
                }}>대구시</button>
            <button
                className="itemList"
                onClick={() => {
                    api(5)
                }}>광주시</button>
            <button
                className="itemList"
                onClick={() => {
                    api(6)
                }}>부산시</button>
            <button
                className="itemList"
                onClick={() => {
                    api(39)
                }}>제주시</button> */}
        </div>
        <p className="findingplace">시/군/구</p>
        <div className="containerList2">
            <SubArea
              list = {subArea}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
 );
 };

 export default Restaurant;
```

SubArea component ⬇

```
const SubArea = ({list}) => {

console.log(list)
const areaBtn = (list) => {
    let tmp = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        tmp.push(<button className="itemList2">{tmp[i]}</button>)
    }

    return tmp;
}

return (

    <div className="containerList2">
        {areaBtn}
    </div>
);
};

export default SubArea;
```

I want to know How to operate this.
And if some way to solve problem exist, I want to know how to combine these two components.

Comment: Why actually do you want to combine components? Can you explain what challenges you are facing while merging?

Comment: It is just my curiosity. I want to know how combine two component, and what difference with these ways. If clicked Button, that result isn't reflect right away. So I separated component. Before this, I worked on only on component.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `areaBtn` has a parameter and you call that one without. Try like this :

```
const SubArea = ({list}) => {

console.log(list)

 const areaBtn = (list) => {
    return list.map((tmp) => (
       <button className="itemList2">{tmp}</button>
    ));
 }


}

return (

    <div className="containerList2">
        {areaBtn(list)}
    </div>
);
};

export default SubArea;
```